# Issue with the conda environment name(missing)

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have created an environment using:

`conda create --prefix C:\Users\Dell\Dropbox\DjangoProjects\webenv python=3.6`

After executing: `conda env list` I noticed that the environment name is missing for the new environment I just created.

[image]

I can activate using: `activate C:\Users\Dell\Dropbox\DjangoProjects\webenv`
but it does not show any name.

Now the question is how can I provide the specific name for newly created environment?

Answer (score 3):

This is was an issue with `conda` but is now  [closed](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5537). You should upgrade to conda version 4.4 if its not already running with this version. You may run the following commands and create a new env again:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I'm pretty sure that if you create an environment with the `prefix` option, it doesn't get a name and you have to use the full path always to activate it.

Comment: It seems like it solved the issue for me. You need to restart the conda prompt as well. Thanks